# Microsoft Graph API SDK .NET Issues getting other users emails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph SDK as downloaded from NuGet (1.2). I authenticate to Azure AD (using ADAL).

I am using Client Credentials flow (not authenticated as any particular user) and am using Application Permission roles to access resources.

We are going to set up one service mailbox with a bunch of aliases. The aliases are given to the clients. This is so they are emailing an address that has a meaningful name to them.

My app will run as a service, and routinely scan new emails in this inbox. It should find the To address, and depending on what alias was used, file the email in a location relevant to that client.

The resource I want is: `GET /users/<id | userPrincipalName>/messages`

However, there doesn't appear to be a method in the SDK for it.

I can get users with this:

```
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage filteredUsers = 
                   graphApi.Users.Request()
                                 .Filter("userPrincipalName eq 'user@domain.com'")
                                 .GetAsync().Result;
```

When I loop through the collection, I can see that the User has a 'Messages' property, but it is always null.

If I manually build a request message with HttpClient I can get the messages.

The second problem is that the Recipient property is always the userPrincipalName of the mailbox. How can I get the alias that was used by the sender?

Comment: I can see from another users SO question that I won't be able to get the email as a file (or in bytes) to do anything with anyway. So I will have to use EWS.

Comment: You can use EWS with a client credentials grant from Azure AD also, but you need to authenticate the client with an X.509 certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you are able to get your collection of users successfully, you have to make another request to receive the messages. This would look something like:

```
IUserMessagesCollectionPage userMessages = 
             graphApi.Users["user_id"].Messages.Request()
             .GetAsync().Result;
```

To answer your second question, at this time you cannot access the original recipient through the Graph API, but you *can* do this through EWS. This is due to the fact that you can only retrieve the SMTP message headers through EWS. You can read more about how to do this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh545614(v=exchg.140).aspx).

If this is something you believe is valuable to you in the Graph, I would encourage you to post it in our [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

If you want to get the email as a file, you can simply get the body as bytes through the SDK:

```
byte[] asBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message.Body.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks Caitlin, I'll mark this as answered as it explains the main part of my question which was how to make a request for a users messages which worked for me. Regarding getting the message as a file, I needed the whole file as an EML. I guess it's an 'export' which I found a resource for doing using EWS here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672317(v=exchg.150).aspx