# Microsoft Graph API .NET not able to read shared mail

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

First post...here goes.  I am trying to display email from a shared mailbox but run into "ErrorAccessDenied Access is denied. Check credentials and try again".

The user does have permission to the mailbox, I can access/read email in Outlook and in O365 portal. In my app I have also assigned Mail.Read.Shared and Mail.ReadWrite.Shared scopes.

At first I tried Graph Explorer

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<userPrincipalNameOfSharedMailbox>/messages
```

but same ErrorAccessDenied, assumed Graph Explorer did not have Mail.Read.Shared scope.

Next I tried to modify [Microsoft Graph Snippets Sample for ASP.NET 4.6](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample)

I added Mail.Read.Shared and Mail.ReadWrite.Shared and was prompted to accept these permissions

• Read and write mail you can access

• Read mail you can access

but I get the same error when I try get mail from the shared mailbox

```
IUserMessagesCollectionPage messages = await graphClient.Users["userPrincipalNameOfSharedMailbox"].Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

There was a similar post here [Microsoft Graph API SDK .NET Issues getting other users emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671453/microsoft-graph-api-sdk-net-issues-getting-other-users-emails) and the answer implies this is possible.  If it is can anyone provide some insight as to what I am missing?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, accessing shared messages is not supported for the authorization_code flow, but it *is* supported for the client_credentials flow. In order to incorporate this functionality, you will have to change your flow to incorporate this.

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/) is an article on creating a client_credentials flow app if you are interested in going this route.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I was able to get it to work.  Will that functionality be added later, what is the purpose of the Mail.Read.Shared scope, or am I misunderstanding something.  To me that scope, Mail.Read.Shared, should allows access to the shared mail items.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the Mail.Read.Shared scope implies that this is available. This feature is something we are working on, but unfortunately I do not have an ETA on this.