# How to access shared mailbox using Microsoft Graph in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application which can access my mailbox. I created the application following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet?tutorial-step=1

I have then adapted the application to read mail. This works fine for my own mail. However, I need to access a shared inbox which I do have access to and can read emails in my outlook.

I have attempted to do this using the following code:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Message>> GetMailAsync()
        {
            var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();


            var mail = await graphClient.Users["usersemail@somewhere.com"].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request()
                .GetAsync();

            return mail;
        }
```

However, I am getting an unauthorized error:

[authorization error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjJKm.png)
Here is my authorization code:

```
private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
        {
            return new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        // Get the signed in user's id and create a token cache
                        string signedInUserId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        HttpContextWrapper httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                        TokenCache tokenStore = new SessionTokenStore(signedInUserId,
                            httpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();

                        var idClient = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                            appId, redirectUri, new ClientCredential(appSecret),
                            tokenStore, null);

                        var accounts = await idClient.GetAccountsAsync();

                        // By calling this here, the token can be refreshed
                        // if it's expired right before the Graph call is made
                        var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
                                    graphScopes.Split(' '), accounts.FirstOrDefault());

                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                    }));
        }
```

I have added permissions within the application [Image of app permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7wr9.png)

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here? Some posts sugeest it can't be done this way ([Microsoft Graph API .NET not able to read shared mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813610/microsoft-graph-api-net-not-able-to-read-shared-mail), [Microsoft Graph API SDK .NET Issues getting other users emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671453/microsoft-graph-api-sdk-net-issues-getting-other-users-emails)), but I can get it working in the graph explorer.

Any help appreciated including advice on how I can improve my questions.

Comment: _"I am getting an unauthorized error"_ - but the error message says the error is `ResourceNotFound`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, I hadn't set the appSettings correctly.

I added "User.Read Mail.Read.Shared" to my PrivateSettings.Config as shown:

```
   <add key="ida:AppScopes" value="User.Read Calendars.Read" />
<add key="ida:AppScopes" value="User.Read Mail.Read" />
<add key="ida:AppScopes" value="User.Read Mail.Read.Shared" />
```

Hope this helps someone.